# How to import an createEmotionServer in remix js

Tags: remix, emotion

In remix.js I, want to import createEmotionServer from @emotion/server/create-instance. It is giving me, error. Is there is something wrong in this code.

The import statement is this:

```
import createEmotionServer from "@emotion/server/create-instance";
```

It is just an import statement. But in remix it is showing the error

```
Error: Cannot find module '@emotion/server/create-instance'
```

Is there is any other module path from which I need to import it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install server emotion:

```
npm install @emotion/server
```